# Tips and tricks for using emacs to develop a ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, emacs

What are the best modes, configuration settings, or anything that makes developing a ruby on rails app in emacs better.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should try all the RoR and settle on the one you like best.

First you should check out Marshall Vandegrift's [excellent screencast](http://platypope.org/yada/emacs-demo/) using ECB, ruby-mode, emacs-rails, and some other stuff.  It gives you a good feel for how cool writing RoR on Emacs can be.

In short here are some of the modes you should try:

- [Rinari](http://rinari.rubyforge.org/) - A simple framework for getting around your code, running tests, and managing consoles, web-servers, etc.  It's minimalistic and revolves around a series of key-bindings.
- [Emacs-rails](http://rubyforge.org/projects/emacs-rails/) - the grandfather of Emacs RoR modes.  It hasn't been updated in a while, and in fact the primary homepage no longer exists.  But it's quite powerful and lets you do almost everything.
- [Emacs-rails-reloaded](http://github.com/dima-exe/emacs-rails-reloaded) - This is a re-design of the original emacs-rails, I believe by the same guy.  It uses the the great [anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) mode to help you find things and get around.  I am using this AND rinari currently.

Here are some other modes that are useful:

- [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) - the Emacs Code Browser. Use it for project management, and getting around your code.
- [Yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) - provides all kinds of useful snippets, automatically inserted with the TAB key.
- [Nxhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) - For editing rhtml, erb, etc.

More modes you might try:

- [Ri](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RiEl) - for viewing ri documentation inline.
- [Flymake-ruby](http://github.com/purcell/emacs.d/blob/master/site-lisp/flymake-ruby/flymake-ruby.el) - on the fly syntax checking.
- [Ri](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RiEl) - for viewing ri documentation

Oh and of course you need ruby-mode, which comes with the ruby source, and is maintained by Matz himself.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sublime answer, thanks! Can you please provide some more details on how Rinari and Emacs-rails-reloaded play together?

Comment: To be honest I don't use emacs-rails-reloaded anymore. It has not been updated since 2009 and I'm not even sure it works with newer versions of rails. Lately I've found that Rinari is all I need to navigate a rails app.

Answer (score 6):

`rspec-mode` (run single or multiple specs easily)

`js2-mode` (JavaScript syntax highlighting)

`ido` (find files/buffers in your project super quickly)

Answer (score 4):

Since I am new to rails (and emacs), I don't want to use rinari right away.  I find that if a tool does too much magic for me I don't learn the details as quickly as I would like.  I think I will use it eventually.  For now, however, I set up a bunch of shells that I spawn in emacs for RAILS 3 and just switch between them to do my work.  I prefix them with tmr so that I can easily find them.

```
   (defun tmr-spork-shell ()
      "Invoke spork shell" ; Spork - love that name
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "spork")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "spork\n"))

    (defun tmr-devlog-shell ()
      "Tail the development log, shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "devlog")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "tail -f log/development.log\n"))

    (defun tmr-testlog-shell ()
      "Tail the test log, shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "testlog")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "tail -f log/test.log\n"))

    (defun tmr-server-shell ()
      "Invoke rails ui server shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "server")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "rails s\n"))

    (defun tmr-db-shell ()
      "Invoke rails dbconsole shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "dbconsole")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "rails dbconsole\n"))

    (defun tmr-console-shell ()
      "Invoke rails console shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "console")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "rails console\n"))

    ; I like to run all my tests in the same shell
    (defun tmr-rspec-shell ()
      "Invoke rspec shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "rspec")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n"); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc
      (process-send-string nil "rspec spec\n")) ; This is debatable, since spork wont be up yet

    ; The shell where I do most of my work
    (defun tmr-shell ()
      "Invoke plain old shell"
      (interactive)
      (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create (generate-new-buffer-name "sh")))
      (shell (current-buffer))
      (process-send-string nil "cd .\n")); makes sure rvm variables set with .rvmrc

    ; My everyday ide
    (defun tmr-ide-lite ()
      "Spawn several shells for a mini Rails IDE"
      (interactive)
      (progn (tmr-spork-shell)
             (tmr-shell)
             (tmr-server-shell)
             (tmr-rspec-shell)))

    ; When I am doing a big debug session
    (defun tmr-ide-full ()
      "Spawn several shells for a full Rails IDE"
      (interactive)
      (progn (tmr-spork-shell)
             (tmr-shell)
             (tmr-server-shell)
             (tmr-console-shell)
             (tmr-db-shell)
             (tmr-devlog-shell)
             (tmr-testlog-shell)
             (tmr-rspec-shell)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Another mode that I find useful that has not been mentioned is `web-mode`. It is useful for writing views, and handles .html.erb files very well. It features syntax highlighting and tag completion, among other things. You can find it at [here](http://web-mode.org).

Answer (score 3):

Since all of the entries here are 8+ years old, I thought I would mention `projectile-rails` (found [here](https://github.com/asok/projectile-rails)). It is currently maintained (last commit as of this writing is Aug 10, 2021) and, along with other functionality provided by `projectile-mode`, full-featured enough for most Rails projects. I find it easy enough to use with a couple of aliases:

```
(defalias 'gt 'projectile-rails-goto-file-at-point)
(defalias 'gtv 'projectile-rails-find-current-view)
```