# What are the helpful packages for Emacs to do ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs

I would like to know the best Emacs plugins for developers using the Ruby on Rails framework.

Comment: The people who monitor the Emacs tag for this forum are really strict about the question being only programming related -- e.g., sample code that almost works with some help needed to fix it.  They generally vote to close whenever the question broadly seeks recommendations and opinions.  Consider posting your question on https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs -- they love questions over there that elicit recommendations and opinions.   I won't be voting to close this question here, but everyone else will.  Alternatively, try and think of a way to narrow the scope of this question to elicit an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to have an awesome emacs config you should install these packages:

- inf-ruby
- projectile
- projectile-rails
- robe-mode
- web-mode
- rvm
- flymake-ruby
- flymake-easy
- flymake-css
- flymake-sass
- flymake-coffee
- flymake-haml
- flymake-html-validator
- haml-mode
- yaml-mode
- slim-mode
- sass-mode
- coffee-mode
- feature-mode

if you were using vimux you would like to replace projectile and projectile-rails with    emacs-rails-reloaded

by the way if you happen to be a vim user then you should checkout spacemacs.spacemacs has predefined configuration layers for html and ruby on rails.

for ruby as well as ruby on rails

- bundler
- chruby
- company
- enh-ruby-mode
- evil-matchit
- flycheck
- popwin
- rbenv
- robe
- rspec-mode
- rubocop
- ruby-mode (should be avaliable by default)
- ruby-test-mode
- ruby-tools
- rvm
- smartparens
- rake

Comment: rinari is alternative to projectile and projecitle-rails. But i am sure you would love projecitle more.

Answer (score 2):

You may find my 2014 [post](https://lorefnon.me/2014/02/02/configuring-emacs-for-rails.html) on configuring emacs as a productive development environment for Rails helpful. It primarily covers projectile, robe and rvm integration.

While both [emacs-rails-reloaded](https://github.com/dmexe/emacs-rails-reloaded) and [rinari](https://github.com/eschulte/rinari) have been somewhat popular at a time, their development has languished. [Projectile-rails](https://github.com/asok/projectile-rails) is maintained much more actively.

In particular my overall experience with [helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) and [projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) has been very good and would strongly recommend in favor of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the modes you should try:

[Rinari](http://rinari.rubyforge.org/) - A simple framework for getting around your code, running tests, and managing consoles, web-servers, etc. It's minimalistic and revolves around a series of key-bindings.

Emacs-rails - the grandfather of Emacs RoR modes. It hasn't been updated in a while, and in fact the primary homepage no longer exists. But it's quite powerful and lets you do almost everything.

[Emacs-rails-reloaded](https://github.com/dmexe/emacs-rails-reloaded) - This is a re-design of the original emacs-rails. It uses the the great anything mode to help you find things and get around. 
Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429373/tips-and-tricks-for-using-emacs-to-develop-a-ruby-on-rails-app) answer.
You can find some other useful stuff [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RubyOnRails)